# GWT - Load Search Results Incrementally - Without Pagination

Tags: ajax, gwt, pagination

Front End: GWT
Middle Ware: EJB

I have a search screen which can bring back several thousands of records (note that there is no pagination).

Right now, the GWT layer makes an RPC call to the RPC service and that makes a local call to the EJB, and gets back the sorted result set. Now the part that paints this data on the view, takes a lot of time.

I would like to know if any of you have created a similar page, where the records get loaded on to the screen, say 100 records at a time or so, using asynch calls so that the records in the page will get loaded sequentially, while the user is scrolling down gradually.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this? http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList
Try to scroll that list and you will see.